# При сохранении в csv python выдает ошибку кодирования

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, utf-8, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь распарсить `html` страничку, потом все данные переложить в `Dataframe` и его уже сохранить в `CSV`, все операции отрабатывали нормально, но как только начинаю сохранять в `csv`, то система выдает ошибку:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 49: character maps to

Не так давно сталкивался, что такая ошибка может возникать не напрямую от кодека, например у меня она выскакивала, когда попадал сторонний файл в папку с html файлами.
Уже перепробовал все варианты, не могу найти в чем ошибка.

Код программы:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column':['test']
})

path = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\folder'
os.chdir(path)

def main(x):
    html = open(x)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find_all('a', class_='title-link')
    for i in div:
        b = i.get_text()
        df.loc[len(df)]=[b]
        print(df)
    return df

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    main(filename)

df.to_csv('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\out.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Полная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/dataset/parser.py", line 23, in 
main(filename)
File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/dataset/parser.py", line 14, in main
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\dataset\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 244, in __init__
markup = markup.read()
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 49: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Что-то у вас скрипт в вопросе сломан, почините :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, `BeautifulSoup` попытался файл открыть и считать не в той кодировке, что должна была.

В стеке трассы видно, что файл был считан как `cp1251` (`...lib\encodings\cp1251.py`). Это случилось потому-что в функции `open` если не указывать кодировку будет использоваться системная.

Решение будет через указание кодировки:

```
html = open(x, encoding='utf-8')
```

---

Дело в том, что когда в `BeautifulSoup` передается файловый объект, тот сам считывает его и после парсит.

Поэтому, можно самостоятельно считать из файла, например в строку в нужной кодировке:

```
with open(x, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    html = f.read()
```

Либо, считать байтами и доверить парсеру самостоятельно их кодировать:

```
with open(x, 'rb') as f:
    html = f.read()
```

Comment: Автор загадочен, получил на Тостере такой же ответ от меня, но никак не среагировав пошёл писать вопрос на SO. Не удивлюсь, если и здесь потеряется.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, хех :)

Comment: Спасибо! Последнее решение сработало, остальные тоже выдвали какие-то ошибки.